# "à en faire craquer ses fonds de culotte": Is this expression used metaphorically?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

I just heard this colloquial sentence:

> Mon copain raffole de ma tarte. À chaque fois, il s’en remplit la panse **à en faire craquer ses fonds de culotte** !

The idea of "eating tarts to his heart's content" is expressed by the part "s’en remplit la panse", but I wonder exactly what meaning the subsequent phrase "à en faire craquer ses fonds de culotte" adds to the sentence?

Is it related somehow to a similar expression "***user ses fonds de culotte***" that is used almost always metaphorically?

Comment: remplir la panse is to stuff oneself. To eat to one's heart's content is very polite.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a metaphor too, more precisely an hyperbole which suggests the friend has an immediate weight gain causing his pants seams to crack...

It is certainly related to the more common phrase *user ses fonds de culotte*.

I have never heard *fonds de culotte* outside this set expression.

Comment: Do you think this expression is similar to "his stomach bursting at the seams", though the part that is tearing is his pants, not his shirt? On another note: is it common to refer to mens pants as "culotte"?

Comment: @Alone-zee In France « culotte » is more for girls nowadays, but we kept the old word for old expressions and for talking about children underwear.

Comment: Indeed, before the French revolution, the *culottes* (breeches) were worn by healthy men while women were dressed with *robes/jupes*. An expression like *porter la culotte* makes that clear.

Comment: He stuffs  himself enough to split his britches.